# Пакет php5-mysql недоступен sentos. Как установить?

Tags: pdo, centos

Пытаюсь установить PDO на Centos, однако при команде

```
yum install php5-mysql
```

получаю такую ошибку.

Comment: Для начала убедиться, что он есть в yum и называется именно так. В интернете полно статей по установке. Непонятно почему вы не воспользовались ими, а написали сразу сюда

Comment: # yum search php-mysql